# How to build for docker (rush monorepo)?

Tags: production, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace, rush

So I have a monorepo using rush (pnpm).

I have multiple applications and multiple libraries. Applications depend on libraries, and libraries depend on libraries.

I know pnpm creates a node_modules folder using symlinks.

I know docker copy directive won't follow symlinks.

How to build an application using rush (pnpm) without using symlinks (only for production deployment)

Comment: Isn’t that what ‘rush deploy’ is for? Just started using rush so maybe I’m off but it should make the bundles for you?

Answer (score 0):

https://rushjs.io/pages/commands/rush_deploy/

After building the repo, "rush deploy" can be used to prepare a deployment by
copying a subset of Rush projects and their dependencies to a target folder,
which can then be uploaded to a production server. The "rush deploy" behavior
is specified by a scenario config file that must be created first, using the
"rush init-deploy" command.